# How to #include inside .cpp file?

Tags: c++, compilation, include, c-preprocessor, header-files

In the following example, the FileA header is included in FileB header; Some of the classes in FileB.h are forwardly declared inside FileA.h;

in FileA.h

```
//Forward Declaration.
class classB;

//Main classes.
class ClassA
{
//...
private:
void MemberFunction(ClassB* PtrToClassBObj);
}
```

In FileB.h

```
//Includes.
#include FileA.h

//Main classes.
class ClassB
{
//...
public:
int MemberVariable = 0;
}
```

Then in FileA.cpp

```
#include FileA.h

//Member functions definitions.
void ClassA::MemberFunction(ClassB* PtrToClassBObj)
{
if(PtrToClassBObj)
PtrToClassBObj->MemberVariable++;
}
```

Is that enough to make FileA.cpp capable of accessing public members of said classes from FileB.h? or should FileA.cpp itself include FileB.h? And was the forward declaration needed (assuming no use of the class name inside FileA.h, and only used inside FileA.cpp exclusively)? What is the general best practice advice if any?

Comment: FileA.cpp should include FileB.h. This question should explain what you need to resolve the circular header dependency: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: Since `FileB.h` includes `FileA.h` and you're using a member of `ClassB`, you should be able to just include `FileB.h`

Comment: FileB.h does not use ClassA at all, and as such should not be including FileA.h. Only include what is actually used. Keep your includes as minimal and isolated as possible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nope, it's including it to help frame the context of the question, obviously.

Comment: @Physician perhaps, but what I described is better practice than what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that enough to make FileA.cpp capable of accessing public members of said classes from FileB.h?

No, it is not "enough" - the full definition of `ClassB` needs to be visible.

> or should FileA.cpp itself include FileB.h?

It should, because it uses the class at `PtrToClassBObj->MemberVariable`.

> was the forward declaration needed

As presented, no - you can remove `#include FileA.h` from `FileB` and make `FileA` include `FileB`.

> (assuming no use of the class name inside FileA.h, and only used inside FileA.cpp exclusively)?

Assuming there is no use of `ClassB` inside `FileA.h`, there is no use for forward declaring `ClassB`, so the forward declaration is not needed. The assumption conflicts with presented code, as the symbol `ClassB` is used in `ClassA::MemberFunction` declaration.

> What is the general best practice advice if any?

Follow code guidelines. Do not write spaghetti code and do not have circular dependencies. Prefer clear, easy-to-understand, readable code structured in a hierarchical tree. Compile with all warnings enabled, use code linters and sanitizers. Exercise regularly. Eat healthy.